# CLRS Insertion Sort Implmentation

Tags: algorithm, insertion-sort, clrs

I was going through Insertion Sort algo in CLRS. I am not sure which is the right implementation -

Algo from CLRS -
[image: CLRS pseudocode]

Implementation 1 :

```
def Insertion_sort():
list = [3,5,1,7,2,4]
for j in xrange(1,len(list)):
    i = j-1
    while i>=0 and list[i] > list[j]:
        swap(list, i, j)
        j = i
        i = i-1
```

Implementation 2:

```
def Insertion_sort2():
list = [3,5,1,7,2,4]
for j in range(1,len(list)):
    i = j-1;
    while i>=0 and list[i]>list[j]:
        i = i-1;
    swap(list, i+1, j)
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you try them? (And where do you see `swap` in the CLRS algorithm?)

Comment: Both of them work for me.

Comment: @user3886450: For clarity, for a sorting function to work, it has to work on all inputs. Try the second one on the various prefixes of `[3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 4]` (and, if you like, change the `4` to a `6`), and you will see that the fact that it happened to result in a sorted list in *this particular case* was simply fortuitous. (Or, arguably, inopportune since the result is to hide an obvious bug.)

Comment: Neither of your examples will compile with `javac` or `g++`.

Comment: @stackoverflowuser2010: that's unsurprising since they are written in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither of the proposed functions actually reproduces the algorithm as presented in CLRS.

The code in lines 5 through 8 in the CLRS algorithm do a *rotation* of a subsequence of the list ending at index `j`. That will insert the value at index `j` in the correct point in the prefix of the list.

Your first function does the same thing, but instead of doing a rotation it does a series of swaps. The rotation is much more efficient, since it only modifies each list item once instead of twice.

Your second function just does a single swap, which moves the value at element `j` into the right spot, but does not preserve the order of the rest of the prefix of the list. So it is a lot faster, but produces an incorrect result. (The fact that it happened to produce a sorted output with your test vector is amusing, but if you look at the successive prefixes at each insertion point, you'll see that it doesn't really work. Try sorting just `[2, 3, 1]`, for example.)

Answer (score -1):

Both are correct and both run in O(n^2) time, but the second implementation is better because you do only 1 swap for each element of the list, whereas for the first implementation you do O(n^2) swaps. The first implementation swaps the out-of-place number with the next number until the number is in the correct place, whereas the second implementation finds the correct index for the out-of-place number before swapping the number into its final correct position. Although swaps are O(1) time, they take longer than simply decrementing a number.

Comment: Maybe you should try the second one on a wider selection of inputs. It should be evident that it doesn't work, because one swap is not sufficient to insert a value into a sorted list.

Comment: What are you talking about? It does work. And one swap is definitely sufficient.

Comment: Try it with the input vector `[3,5,1,7,2,6]`. Or just `[3, 5, 1]`. The fact that it worked with `[3, 5, 1, 7, 2, 4]` was pure luck. (And how would you convert `[3, 5, 1]` to `[1, 3, 5]` with one swap? It seems obvious that one swap is not sufficient. One *rotation* is sufficient.)